# Button not calling function correctly

Tags: javascript, html, function, event-handling

I am trying to call a function on a button click, but for some reason the button will not call the function. Dreamweaver does not show any syntax errors. Can anyone tell me why the button is not working?

```
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
   <head>
   <title></title>


<script type="text/javascript">

        var imgObj = 0;
        var imgObj1 = 0;
        var animate;
        var animate1;

        function init(){
           imgObj = document.getElementById('red');
           imgObj.style.position= 'relative';
           imgObj.style.left = '0px';
           imgObj1 = document.getElementById('blue');
           imgObj1.style.position = 'relative';
           imgObj1.style.left = '0px';
        }

        function moveRight(){
           imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left = 0) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + 'px';

           animate = setTimeout(moveRight(), 1000); 
           imgObj1.style.left = parseInt(imgObj1.style.left = 0) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + 'px';

           animate1 = setTimeout(moveRight(), 1000); 
           if (imgObj.style.left >= 1000px || imgObj1.style.left >= 1000px)
            {
                break;
                else if
                {
                    imgObj.style.left>= 1000
                    MessageBox.show("The Red Car has won the Race!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.show("The Blue Car has won the Race!");
                }

            }
        }           
</script>

</head>

<body onload = "init()">

   <form>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="moveRight()" />
    <br/><br/><br/><br><br/><br/><br/>
    <img id="red" src="redcar.png" alt="Car 1"/>
    <br/><br/><br/><br>
    <img id="blue" src="bluecar.png" alt ="Car 2" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the button click suppose to do?

Comment: One thing; `setTimeout(moveRight(), 1000);` should be `setTimeout(moveRight, 1000);`

Comment: Does the button click work? Aka, does adding an alert give you that alert? Is imgObj found correctly? And then yes, the timeout syntax.

Comment: You've missed a curly brace, and the condition in the first "else if". You have two `<head>` tags also. You've to check the 1000px values, because I'm pretty suer that they must be quoted.

Comment: `parseInt(imgObj.style.left = 0)` makes no sense.

Comment: 1) if (imgObj.style.left >= 1000px || imgObj1.style.left >= 1000px) literally means 190px >=1000px || 190px >=1000px. Rectify it.
2) what is break; doing in if else condition?

Comment: gurvinder372 - The button is supposed to call the moveRight function. This function will move the images across the screen until one or the other hits 1000 pixels. Shilly - I just added an alert and that it is not displaying.

Comment: andy - I added that so that it wouldn't add the previews amount of pixels each time the function is called. ie if the last random was 50 it wouldn't add 50 + the next random number. Prem - my thought process was that if the 190>=1000 then it will repeat. I added the break so that the images wouldnt continue to move across the page.

Comment: @Shadough: looks like Tibrogargan have posted the correct answer. He just gave you the fish didn't taught you fishing. Console >>>> Dreamweaver

Comment: @Prem Bikram Limbu I taught him one thing: Stop using Dreamweaver for coding.

Comment: @PremBikramLimbu youre right prem. I actually just got it today after the CIS tutor recommended it lol. I'll take your guys advice from here on out!

Comment: @Shadough Dreamweaver is good for layout, not so good for coding.  Chrome is good for coding/debugging but has zero layout tools.  Maybe use both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there are so many errors that it's difficult to know where to start.  The first answer to your question is that the button did nothing because your code doesn't compile.  I don't know why Dreamweaver didn't report an error.  Chrome's developer tools was more than happy to do so.

Here's a "working" version:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgObj = 0;
var imgObj1 = 0;
var animate1;

function init(){
   imgObj = document.getElementById('red');
   imgObj.style.position= 'relative';
   imgObj.style.left = '0px';
   imgObj1 = document.getElementById('blue');
   imgObj1.style.position = 'relative';
   imgObj1.style.left = '0px';
}

function moveRight(){
   var redPosition = parseInt(imgObj.style.left);
   imgObj.style.left = redPosition + Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1) + 'px';
   var bluePosition = parseInt(imgObj.style.left);
   imgObj1.style.left = bluePosition + Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1) + 'px';

   if (redPosition >= 1000 || bluePosition >= 1000)
   {
        if (redPosition >= 1000) {
            alert("The Red Car has won the Race!");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("The Blue Car has won the Race!");
        }
        return;
    }
    animate1 = setTimeout(moveRight, 50);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload = "init()">
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="moveRight()" />
    <br/><br/><br/><br><br/><br/><br/>
    <img id="red" src="redcar.png" alt="Car 1"/>
    <br/><br/><br/><br>
    <img id="blue" src="bluecar.png" alt ="Car 2" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you tell me what all changes that you had to make for you to get it working?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I guess I'll make the switch to Chrome for the time being. With the alerts, I understand that you cannot add custom buttons. Would there be a way to have a dialog box come up with a button to reset the race? The only way I can think of with my limited knowledge would be to have a button hidden on the page that becomes visible once the race is over.

Comment: @Shadough that would work fine, although it might be a better idea to have a button that's disabled until the race is over.  Or use some racing themed imaged.  Flags or something (i.e.  Starts w/ image 1, changes to image 2 when race is over)

Comment: @Tibrogargan: Not nitpicking but alert will always "The Blue Car has won the Race!" because you forgot parseInt() here 
if (imgObj.style.left>= 1000) {
            alert("The Red Car has won the Race!");
        }
I am playing these game now.

Comment: @Prem Bikram Limbu  Good catch.  There's a things that could easily be improved.

Comment: If either of you guys happen to see this let me know. If i change the line of code <input type ="button" value ="start" onclick="moveRight()"/> to <input type = "image" src = "whatever.jpg" onclick="moveRight()"/> the program will no longer run in browser. What gives?